# Getting different results with bindvars in db.Query

Tags: mysql, go

go version : 18.3
github.com/go-sql-driver/mysql v1.6.0

When Query string is
`db.Query("SELECT * FROM logs ORDER BY log_id DESC LIMIT 1,3 ")`

if the log_id == 8

`b, _ := rawValue.([]byte)`

Below is the vscode debug information，b is correct

b: []uint8 len:1,cap 1,[56] ; string():"8"

when i use
`db.Query("SELECT * FROM logs ORDER BY log_id DESC LIMIT ?,? ", 1,3)`

if the log_id == 8

In `b, _ := rawValue.([]byte)`

the info is

b: []uint8 len :0 ,cap:0 ,nil

rawValue is `8` not `56`

and user(string) is work-well in the both.

#### My SQL schema

```
CREATE TABLE logs (  
  `log_id` INT(6) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, 
  `user` VARCHAR(10),
  PRIMARY KEY(log_id)      
);
```

#### code

```golang
    db, _:= sql.Open("mysql", "root:root@tcp(127.0.0.1:3306)/log")
    rows, _ := db.Query("SELECT * FROM logs ORDER BY log_id DESC LIMIT ?,? ", 1, 3)
    col, _ := rows.Columns()
    defer rows.Close()
    count := len(col)
    values := make([]interface{}, count)
    for i := range values {
        var ii interface{}
        values[i] = &ii
    }
    ret := make([]map[string]interface{}, 0)

    fmt.Println("Reading data:")
    for rows.Next() {
        _ = rows.Scan(values...)
        m := make(map[string]interface{}, 0)
        for i, colname := range col {
            rawValue := *(values[i].(*interface{}))
            b, _ := rawValue.([]byte)
            if colname == "log_id" {
                v, _ := strconv.Atoi(string(b))
                m[colname] = v
            } else if colname == "log_msg_id" {
                v, _ := strconv.Atoi(string(b))
                m[colname] = v

            } else {
                v := string(b)
                m[colname] = v
            }

        }
```

Comment: 56 is the ascii code for 8, btw. And you're not checking any of the errors, if you would, you'd know where the problem is.

Comment: You can't use `?` placeholders in a `LIMIT` or `OFFSET` clause.

Comment: Hi @ Tim Biegeleisen, Thanks you. So i can't use `?` placeholders in a LIMIT on db.Query function? In other case ,  I use `?` placeholders in LIMIT on db.SELECT. it work well.

Comment: Hi @mkopriva , Thanks your suggest. Yes i know 56 is the ascii code for 8, my question is  why string  work well. but "int" is not correct

Comment: I add err. All err is nil.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why not just scan the values to a struct like this:

```
type Log struct {
        ID   int64
        Name string
    }

    db, _ := sql.Open("mysql", "root:passwd@tcp(127.0.0.1:3306)/log")
    rows, err := db.Query("SELECT * FROM logs ORDER BY log_id DESC LIMIT ?,? ", 1, 3)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err)
    }

    defer rows.Close()
    var values []Log

    fmt.Println("Reading data:")
    for rows.Next() {
        var log Log
        err = rows.Scan(&log.ID, &log.Name)
        if err != nil {
            fmt.Println(err)
            continue // you need to handle error
        }

        values = append(values, log)
    }
    fmt.Println(values)
```